# Event Participant profile warning:The selected profile is using a custom field which is not assigned to the "Event" being configured

Tags: civievent, profile, 4.6.14

Profile has individual, contact and participant fields only.  All are accessible for user and admin.
Warning is issued when editing the event.  Nothing in error log.  form seems to work, but dedupe rules are not triggering.  This is for anonymous users on Drupal.

Possibly related:

https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17141 *** yes "CiviCRM: access all custom data" is enabled.

https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-15427

https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16979

https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-15595